# how to solve Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `raceday` date NOT NULL,
  `meeting_number` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `event_number` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
 ,`event_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_events_race_meetings` FOREIGN KEY (`raceday`, `meeting_number`) REFERENCES `race_meetings` (`raceday`, `meeting_number`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) 

ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `bet_types` (
  `ao_bet_type` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `bet_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `bet_type_description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_bet_type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number_of_legs` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_order` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bet_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `dividends` (
  `raceday` date NOT NULL,
  `meeting_number` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `event_number` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `bet_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `dividend_number` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `pool_class` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pool_result_type` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dividend_type` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dividend_or_accrual_cents` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_value` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `concession_dividend_flag` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number_of_legs` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`raceday`,`meeting_number`,`event_number`,`bet_type`,`dividend_number`),
  KEY `FKA113AE64360F4F38` (`bet_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKA113AE64360F4F38` FOREIGN KEY (`bet_type`) REFERENCES `bet_types` (`bet_type`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dividends_events` FOREIGN KEY (`raceday`, `meeting_number`, `event_number`) REFERENCES `events` (`raceday`, `meeting_number`, `event_number`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1




@Test
     public void testDividend()

     {
         try
         {

           Dividend d = new Dividend();
          d.setEvent(new Event(new Date(),24,7));
          d.setBetType(new BetType(15));
          d.setDividendNumber(5);
    /*  HibernateUtil.saveOrUpdate(d, postgresSession, true);*/
         HibernateUtil.saveOrUpdate(d, mysqlSession, true);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             e.getLocalizedMessage();

         }
     }

I am getting   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ebet`.`dividends`, CONSTRAINT `fk_dividends_events` FOREIGN KEY (`raceday`, `meeting_number`, `event_number`) REFERENCES `events` (`raceday`, `meeting_number`, `event_number`) ON DELETE CASCA)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
```

how to solve Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: and the data also available in child tables

Comment: add your entities code/mapping

Answer (score 4):

This issue is occurred mainly due of Foreign Key constraints . To avoid this i have simple trick that is Simply use 
`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` 
it will remove effect of foreign key constraints and after execution again use 
`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` 
to continue on the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
BetType betType = new BetType(15);
betType.save();
```

This row of BetType doesn't exist in the database table. That row must be there with the id that your are using in child table and then enter the child record.

You are directly adding the child record without adding the parent record.

Comment: are you sure all about the parent table rows? all the values that you are adding are already in the parent tables? and why don't you use save function since it is to be added newly... i can see your hibernate util, what does true end ? the third arg?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the entities it is guessing, but most likely your relationship is managed by the Event not the Divident so you need to set the Divident on the even object before saving and your OneToOne mapping must be annotated with `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on the Dividient:

```
 Dividend d = new Dividend();
 Event e = new Event(new Date(),24,7);
 e.setDividient(d);
 d.setEvent(e);

 d.setBetType(new BetType(15));
 d.setDividendNumber(5);
 HibernateUtil.saveOrUpdate(d, mysqlSession, true);
```

Or if you dont use cascading you need to explicit save first the event, bet and then divident:

```
Session s = ...
session.save(d.getEvent());
session.save(d.getBet());
session.save(d);
```